# Union between two dataframe columns

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

df1 has these columns: participantid, formid, c1, c2, c3, c4

df2 has these columns: participantid, c5, c6, c7, c8

I want a union of all participantids from the first data frame where formid = 'some value' and all of participantids from the second dataframe. I am only interested in a list of participantids. I am not interested in any of the other columns: c1, c2, c3, c4,...

I have tried:

```
union(df1[df1$formid == "some value", "participantid"], df2["participantid"])
union(df1[df1$formid == "some value", "participantid"], df2[["participantid"]])
union(df1[df1$formid == "some value", "participantid"], df2$participantid)
```

Neither worked.

Any pointers?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I have tried the following code and it works:

```
df1 <- data.frame(participantid = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"),
                 formid = c("F1","F1","F1","F2"),
                 c1 = c(0,0,0,0))

df2 <- data.frame(participantid = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"),
                  c2 = c(0,0,0,0))

union(df1[df1$formid == "F1", "participantid"], df2$participantid)
```

When I run `class(df2$participantid)` or `class(df1[df1$formid == "F1", "participantid"])`, it returns `[1] "factor"`

My real data is coming from CSV files and when I run on this real data `class(df1[df1$formid == "F1", "participantid"])` it returns `[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"` and when I run `class(df2$participantid)` it returns `[1] "character"`. Do you guys know why that is?

Edit #2: I was able to reproduce my predicament using dummy CSV files:

df1 CSV file:

```
participantid,formid,c1
A1,F1,0
A2,F1,0
A3,F1,0
A4,F2,0
```

df2 CSV file:

```
participantid,c2
B1,0
B2,0
B3,0
B4,0
```

When I run the union command above I get this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A1" "A2" "A3"

[[2]]
[1] "B1"

[[3]]
[1] "B2"

[[4]]
[1] "B3"

[[5]]
[1] "B4"
```

with a length() of 5, when it should have been a length of 7. Does this make sense?

I was expecting the output to be either

```
"A1" "A2" "A3" "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4"
```

or

```
"A1" 
"A2" 
"A3" 
"B1" 
"B2" 
"B3" 
"B4"
```

Edit #3: I am going to answer my own question. This worked for me in the end:

```
union(df1[df1$formid == "F1",]$participantid, df2$participantid)
```

Comment: are you sure that `"some value"` is the same data type as `df1$formid`? maybe it is a factor and you're testing a number, and the results are different from what you expect.

Comment: please provide an excerpt from your dataframes

Comment: I wish I could. I am not sure if I can post those real participantids. I will edit my original post to try to clarify.

Comment: It looks your R version is earlier than R 4.0.0, can't you update it?

Comment: Thank you. I have upgraded to R version 4.0.3 but the behavior is the same. ```df1[df1$formid == "F1", "participantid"]``` still does not play nice but ```df1[df1$formid == "F1",]$participantid``` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
union(unique(df1[df1$formid == "some value", 'participantid']), unique(df2$participantid))
```

I used `unique` as I guess you don't need duplicated values.

Comment: This does not work. It puts the participantids from df1 all on a row, and then puts the participantids from df2 on subsequent rows. So, if I am supposed to get 50 participantids from df1 and 100 participantids from df2, the result I get will have 101 rows and I need to have 150. Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't quite follow your comment on rows and "subsequent rows". The code will produce a vector. A long vector may print in different rows. If you want to have the full 150, remove the `unique` parts

Comment: Absolutely @GuedesBF, I should have started there: asking for a reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: I have provided two sample CSV files with output and expected output in the Edit #2 in my original post.